# How to autoload a package without requiring in the init file?

Tags: init-file, package, autoload, require

When you install [clojure-mode](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/master/clojure-mode.el) via `package-install`, you can then open any `.clj` file and automatically enter the mode.

And this works for every subsequent Emacs launch ; Yet, no `(require 'clojure-mode)` (or a custom definition, nothing) has been inserted in the init file.

I carefully reviewed [the clojure-mode.el file](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/master/clojure-mode.el), and found no clue as to how this works. Yes, the main interactive functions and the major modes definitions are autoloaded, and the common clojure file extensions are added to `auto-mode-alist`:

```
;;;###autoload
(progn
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
               '("\\.\\(clj\\|dtm\\|edn\\)\\'" . clojure-mode))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cljc\\'" . clojurec-mode))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cljx\\'" . clojurex-mode))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cljs\\'" . clojurescript-mode)))
```

But this is not enough for the mode I'm working on. I found no way of loading it without explicitly requiring it in the init file..?

What is this magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You discovered most of the answer yourself. When you install `clojure-mode`, you also get a file `clojure-mode-autoloads.el`. That file besides adding the entries you mentioned to `auto-mode-alist`, also defines autoloads for the functions `clojure-mode`, `clojurec-mode`, etc.

Once the autoload file has been loaded (which normally `package-initialize` does on start up), the first time you open a file with extension `.clj`, say, the `auto-mode-alist` variable is consulted. That says that the `clojure-mode` function should be run and the attempt to run it causes `clojure-mode.el` to be loaded (because of the autoload on the `clojure-mode` function).

You can create a similar file of autoloads for your mode (look into `update-file-autoloads` and `update-directory-autoloads` to automate this process) and then require that autoload file from your init file (since `package-initialize` won't do that for you).

Comment: Wait, did you say "and then require that autoload file from your init file"? Closure-mode doesn't do that. The idea is to understand how this works *without touching the init file*..?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Omar ; I don't get this "autoloads in a separate file" business anyway, do you know of some documentation to read about it? I mean, it can't work differently from "normal" plain autoloads, right?

Comment: Wait, it works now. I had an error in my extension file regexp. No `require`, just two `;;;###autoload`s: The major mode definition, and the add to `auto-mode-alist`. Happy camper :)